# Debian 8: unable to locate package

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, debian-jessie

I have installed Debian 8 (from live debian-live-8.7.1-i386-xfce-desktop.iso) on VirtualBox.

I'm trying to do all the steps described here https://wiki.draglet.com/index.php/Manual:Installation_manual

On this step The following Debian 8 packages are required to run draglet:

```
apt-get install exim4 ntp pwgen curl php5-dev php-pear pkg-config nmap libzmq3 libzmq3-dev libapache2-mod-php5 apache2 percona-server-server-5.6 php5-cli php5-mysql php5-curl php5-intl daemontools-run oracle-java8-installer ant ruby-compass libtool-bin
```

when I execute this command I get the output

> unable to locate package

.... I get this message for `ntp`, `pwgen` and other packages.

How can I install them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about installing existing software, not creating new software.

Comment: @MSalters The question is indeed helpful if you are just getting started in Linux and drowning at that time

Comment: @Arefe: Wrong site, not necessarily a bad question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains lines similar to the following?

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main non-free contrib
```

You might want to remove any lines that are prefixed with `cdrom:` if they exist as well.

Remember you will need to edit the file as a root and than run apt-get update. Once you do this try installing the packages again.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Debian 8 (live with Genome v 8.0) and I have the same issue mentioned. Please, update the `/etc/apt/sources.list`file to the newest sources and run `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`. Then do a restart and I hope it will be okay then. For example, after updating, my sources list is,

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
```